# How come my code cannot calculate count correctly in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to limit keyword input.

Whenever a user enter a keyword, it will append 'span' to that keyword, e.g.

like the html code below.

I can limit words, but the count is not accurate but when it reach 5, it stop entering.

If I refresh page, I can enter one more again, then stop me again too.

The weird things, it doesn't work if I use id for `var count=$('#result_tag').text()`. I have to use class.

I had tried to change `/\S+/g to /\s+/g`, not working, I have to keep S capital.

JQuery:

```
$( "#tag" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {

        var count=$('.result_tag').text();
        var words=count.match(/\S+/g).length;

        if(words >= 8 ){

            alert('No more than eight words');  
        }       

        //save tag after press enter key   
        else if ( event.which==188 || event.which == 13 ) {

        event.preventDefault();
        //codes will do the action
```

HTML:

```
<span id="result_tag" class="result_tag">keyword that user enter</span>
<span id="result_tag" class="result_tag">keyword that user enter</span>
<span id="result_tag" class="result_tag">keyword that user enter</span>
```

Comment: You cannot have same ID's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ids should be unique, that's why "it doesn't work if I use id".

As for your other problem, your method of counting seems a little convoluted. Sounds like all you need to do is count the spans themselves:

`var words = $('.result_tag').length;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `length` property to get the count of keywords.

```
    $("#tag").on("keydown", function(event) 
    {
         var count = $('.result_tag').length;
         if (count >= 8) 
         {
               alert('No more than eight words');
         }

         ...........
         ...........
```

Comment: FYI: _The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead._